# Changing a ComboBox from DropDown to DropDownList I lose options

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Specifically, in my original design, I had Text comments in my ComboBox at load-up time, but then realised that users could type into the box, so I changed the DropDownStyle to DropDownList. Unfortunately, whilst this prevents the user from typing into the box, it also removes the Text from my VS2010 design and also ignores my C# updates to the Text in the program.

Is this normal behaviour or do I have a problem, or do I need to do this via another parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your `DropDownStyle` on `DropDown`.

now on `KeyPress` event add the following:

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: I think I may have to kill the person who told me that C# was easy to learn !!!

I have added 2 new Methods, "private void KAELCcomboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, EventArgs e)" & "private void KAELCcomboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, EventArgs e)" but if I type into KAELCcomboBox1, neither of these Methods are invoked.

Also, when I type "e." inside either of these, I don't get "Handled" as an Intellisense option, just "Equals", "GetHashCode", "GetType" & "ToString".